# How to trigger animator animation once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a mecanim character that I have set up animations for in the animator. I added a 4 triggers to trigger the different animations. My question is, what is the best way to trigger the run animation when a the left/right keyboard button is pressed? What I have now is that the animations keeps getting triggered over and over again because I have the code in an `Update()`. What can I do so it only gets triggered once and loops through that animation?

I have this working:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class AnimationController : MonoBehaviour {

    Animator animator;

    bool running = false;

    void Start() {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetButton("Horizontal")) {
            if(!running) {
                animator.SetTrigger("Run");
                running = true;
            }
        }

        if(Input.GetButtonUp("Horizontal")) {
            animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
            running = false;
        }

    }
}
```

But it seems like it is more that what is needed to accomplish this task, especially as the actions and animations list grows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`animator.SetTrigger` got an inner boolean that becomes true when you enter the state and becomes false when it comes out of the state so there is no need for bools and if you check`Has Exit Time` property in out transition event it would wait for the animation to finish [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Transition.html) you can see it in the docs

Comment: What about looping animations?

Comment: for looping animations it is better not to  use triggers at all , triggers are for one time animations that you want to come back from when they end

Comment: for things like walking and running  you should make a float varaible in mecanim parameters like speed and set it and in transitions check if the speed is greater than 0 then walk if greater than 10 then run